# Getting Started with IL (Intermediate Language)

Tags: .net, intermediate-language

Can anyone suggest any good resources for getting started with IL. Specifically if anyone knows of any GOOD books or screencasts I would appreciate the feedback.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/155357/what-are-the-best-resources-for-learning-cil-msil

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> 'Expert .NET 2.0 IL Assembler'

By Serge Lidin

**Darknight**

Answer (score 4):

[CLR via C#](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735621632) has a pretty basic intro into IL and a very in depth explanation as to what goes on in IL behind the scenes.

Comment: Thanks, I actually recently bought the 3rd edition and am looking forward to reading it!